# How do I use multiple where clauses in GHCi?

Tags: haskell, ghci

I'm playing around with GHCi for the first time, and I'm having some trouble writing multi-line functions.
My code is as follows:

```
Prelude> :{
Prelude| let diffSquares lst = abs $ squareOfSums lst - sumOfSquares lst
Prelude|   where
Prelude|     squareOfSums lst = (fst (sumsAndSquares lst))^2
Prelude|     sumOfSquares lst = snd (sumsAndSquares lst)
Prelude|     sumsAndSquares = foldl (\(sms,sqrs) x -> (sms+x,sqrs+x^2)) (0,0)
Prelude| :}
```

It gives the following error:

```
<interactive>:1:142: parse error on input `='
```

Could someone kindly point me in the direction of what I'm missing?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

From the help manual of ghci (http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/6.10.4/html/users_guide/interactive-evaluation.html):

> Such multiline commands can be used with any GHCi command, and the lines between `:{` and `:}` are **simply merged into a single line for interpretation**. That implies that each such group must form a single valid command when merged, and that **no layout rule is used**.

Therefore you must insert a semicolon between each definition, e.g.

```
Prelude> :{
Prelude| let a x = g
Prelude|   where
Prelude|     g = p x x;      {- # <----- # -}
Prelude|     p a b = a + b
Prelude| :}
```

---

Edit: It seems you need a pair of braces instead in the recent version of GHCi.

```
Prelude> :{
Prelude| let { a x = g
Prelude|   where
Prelude|     g = p x x
Prelude|     p a b = a + b
Prelude| }
Prelude| :}
Prelude> a 5
10
```

Comment: nifty, great answer. Never seen or used this before.

Comment: Doesn't work as of GHC 7.6.3 in Ubuntu packages: parse error on input "where"

Comment: @kennytm any docs you can quote on that? can't wrap my head around these strange rules. why do I need curly braces here?

Comment: @constantius: I don't know why, just some trial-and-error.

Comment: I hate Haskell because of such moments :(

Answer (score 7):

[The golden rule of indentation](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Indentation#The_golden_rule_of_indentation): **code which is part of some expression should be indented further in than the beginning of that expression** (even if the expression is not the leftmost element of the line).

```
Prelude> :set +m
```

**Wrong:**

```
Prelude> let foo = x
Prelude|     where x = 1
Prelude| 

<interactive>:3:1:
    parse error in let binding: missing required 'in'
```

**Right:**

```
Prelude> let foo = x
Prelude|      where x = 1
Prelude|
```

No need for braces or semicolons.