# Why does GHCi complaining at where clause?

Tags: haskell, syntax

When I write a code like this:

```
Prelude> let f = (+1) . (*k)
Prelude|     where k = 2
Prelude|
```

I'm having such an error:

```
<interactive>:46:5: parse error on input 'where'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because you are trying to define multiline functions at the prompt. You can check this link to understand how to do that:

[How do I use multiple where clauses in GHCi?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3067885/how-do-i-use-multiple-where-clauses-in-ghci)

Note however that this may not work on all versions. I have GHC version 7.4.2 and face the same issue.

You can use the `+m` flag for multiline function definition, like so:

```
Prelude> :set +m
Prelude> let f = (+1) . (*k)
Prelude|       where k = 2
Prelude|
```

This works on my system.

Otherwise, you could split the function into 2 as:

```
let k = 2
let f = (+1) . (*k)
```

Comment: I have 7.4.2 too, and I always use multiline mode, including this case. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You might want to compare the indentation in my version with yours. I suspect that is the cause.

Comment: Yep! That's the point. I didn't know that 'where' should be indented to the level of '=' in the prev. line.

Comment: @AndrewVershinin The rule is that it has to be indented past the start of the name of the function it's being defined for.  Since you only have once space between `let` and `f`, there's a total of 5 characters in `let f`, so there has to be at least 5 spaces in front of `where`.  Note that for good style most people would recommend that `where` is indented an extra indentation level beyond the start of the name `f`, so since I use 4 spaces as my indent I would put 8 spaces in front of `where`.